# What is the difference between Envoy Proxy and Consul?

Tags: consul, envoyproxy

I am having tough time understanding the distinction between Envoy and Consul. What are the use cases for each one and what are the advantages ? 
They both seem to be providing service mesh, observability and load balancing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consul is a service mesh control plane which uses Envoy as its data plane proxy.

> **Data plane vs. control plane summary**
>
> - **Service mesh data plane**: Touches every packet/request in the system. Responsible for service discovery, health checking, routing, load balancing, authentication/authorization, and observability.
> - **Service mesh control plane**: Provides policy and configuration for all of the running data planes in the mesh. Does not touch any packets/requests in the system. The control plane turns all of the data planes into a distributed system.

The above quote is from a blog post by the creator of Envoy, Matt Klein, entitled [Service mesh data plane vs. control plane](https://blog.envoyproxy.io/service-mesh-data-plane-vs-control-plane-2774e720f7fc). I recommend reading the post in its entirety to better understand the role of a control plane & data plane within a service mesh.

I also recommend watching this video, [Introduction to HashiCorp Consul Connect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8T8t4-hQY74), for specifics of how Consul service mesh works.